# MVC3 online game with standalone C++ server

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm interested in making a web game using MVC3 (or 4) for the front-end website, since this is the web framework that I'm most comfortable working with.  For the sake of example, let's say it's a real-estate game (fun!..)

I've thought long and hard about how to do this in a scalable way, and I've arrived with the following little questions/dilemmas:

**1)  Code the game server logic into the actual web server itself.**

*Advantage:  Web server could make direct use of entity framework, which is fantastic for data manipulation.*

*Problem:  Not scalable - the game would pretty much be limited to a single server, which could potentially become over-populated and slow.  It could potentially work if I used each web server as a single 'realm', but this might put a lot of load on a database server if 10 'realms' were running.*

**2)  Code the game server logic as a separate C++ executable, perhaps even on a separate machine.**

*Advantage:  Scalable - could have multiple web front end servers connected to the game server and not have outages if a any one web server is down.*

*Problem:  Difficult to communicate between the web server and game server.  Presumably, I'd need to setup socket connections and establish some kind of protocol of communication (maybe using XML).  Additionally, the game server would need to become responsible for data storage which seems like an awful waste of MVC's elegant support for entity framework.  Something simple in MVC3 like checking to see if something already exists in the database would become a pretty laborious task if a socket query to another server was required.*

If anybody has any experience with this kind of problem, could you shed any light on how I might best approach it?

Comment: "the game would pretty much be limited to a single server, which could become over-populated and slow very quickly" - you definitely don't lack any confidence :-D

Comment: Gotta at least plan for the worst! ;-).. or best, whichever way you look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already write an ASP.NET application, why don't you try out [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) and write the game server logic with .NET? WCF does all the communication stuff, while the configuration can sometimes get a little bit tricky.